# Can [go-ethereum] and [geth] be synonymized?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are currently two tags for the same framework, Go Ethereum. This is the official implementation of Ethereum for the Go language.

[geth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geth): 310 questions and only two links on the tag wiki

> Go implementation of command line tools for Ethereum blockchain

[go-ethereum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-ethereum): 322 questions and a somewhat better tag wiki

> go-ethereum also known as geth is a golang implementation of the Ethereum protocol.

[GitHub repository for geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) (for further reading/investigation)

I am not sure which direction the synonymization should go... Go Ethereum is the formal name of the project but it is probably most commonly named/referred to as geth. Given the tag wiki and current tag usage, I'd say that *probably* [geth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geth) should be synonymized into [go-ethereum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-ethereum).

Comment: Geth feels like a prime target for "get" typos/fat fingering; I'd prefer the full name here

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Agreed; not to mention "geth" could potentially be used by another language for something someday, whereas "go-ethereum" is... almost certainly never going to run into a conflict.

Comment: I did a very rough & quick check, and surprisingly, I didn't find any mistagging related to "geth" (or possibly, it was maintained really well). No preference from me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think it’s a good idea to synonymize [geth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geth) in favor of [go-ethereum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-ethereum).

- [geth] is an acronym of go-ethereum, it identifies essentially the same thing
- the tag [go-ethereum] belongs to the Go Collective, whereas [geth] seemingly doesn’t, so it can increase visibility of such questions
- the `go-` prefix in [go-ethereum] is consistent with other tags related to Go frameworks (e.g. go-gin, go-echo, go-zap, etc.

On a side note, the term “golang” in the [go-ethereum] tag excerpt should be renamed to just Go, which is the proper name of the programming language.